# Why can't I use Counter in a pandas aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'm trying to do an aggregation in pandas that gives the number of times each value shows up. For example, say I have this dataframe:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  2
```

My desired output is (something like):

```
a b
1 Counter({1: 2, 2: 1})
2 Counter({1: 1, 2: 2})
```

(The reason I want a counter is that in later operations, I want to add them up).

I tried to do it like this:

```
df2 = df.groupby('a').agg({'b': lambda x: Counter(x)})
```

However, the results didn't come back as expected. What I got was:

```
a  b                                                  
1  <built-in method values of Counter object at 0x0000026A7722D780>
2  <built-in method values of Counter object at 0x0000026A7722D990>
```

I've tried using `Counter(list(x))` and `Counter(x.value_counts())` for my lambda function as well but got similar results.

Is there a way I can get a Counter there?

Comment: work fine on my side, python and pandas version ?

Comment: works fine on my side too

Comment: Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit), pandas 0.20.3'

Comment: BTW `pd.crosstab(df.a,df.b)` I think this is better than Counter, since you are using pandas

Comment: @Wen that makes sense, but I'm also going to be doing this for groupby with multiple columns

Comment: @roundsquare pd.crosstab([df.a,df.a1,df.a2],df.b)

Comment: @Wenthansk! That works great! Still curious why the other didn't. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: Just upgraded my pandas to 0.23.3 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop on this, I upgraded pandas from 0.20.3 to 0.23.3 and the above code worked.